# how to get the selected date from the calendar in flutter

Tags: flutter, calendar

I created a calendar, now I want to get the selected date in a variable and pass it to another widget or call it somewhere else in code.

here is my calender code

```
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
  CalendarController _calendarController;
   Widget calendar(){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
      width: double.infinity,
    
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
        
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue[500],Colors.blue[500]]),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.white,
            blurRadius: 5,
            offset: new Offset(0.0, 5)
          )
        ]
      ),
      child: TableCalendar(
          calendarController: _calendarController,
          initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
          
            calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
              canEventMarkersOverflow: true,
              markersColor: Colors.white,
              weekdayStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            
              
              todayColor: Colors.white54,
              todayStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[900], fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              selectedColor: Colors.blue[900],
              outsideWeekendStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
              outsideStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
              weekendStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              renderDaysOfWeek: false,
              
            )));
            
  }
```

and i am calling it here

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new MyAppBar(title: Text("My Attendance")),

    
    drawer:drawer(),
   
    body:Stack(children: <Widget>[
      calendar() //here
```

please help what should i do to get the date in variable, and it should update the variable (like setstate() method will be call ) when user select the other date.

**update (solution):**

```
CalendarController _calendarController;
   Widget calendar(){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
      width: double.infinity,
    
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
        
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue[500],Colors.blue[500]]),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.white,
            blurRadius: 5,
            offset: new Offset(0.0, 5)
          )
        ]
      ),
      child: TableCalendar(  
              initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,  
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(  
                  todayColor: Colors.blue,  
                  selectedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,  
                  todayStyle: TextStyle(  
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,  
                      fontSize: 22.0,  
                      color: Colors.white)  
              ),  
              headerStyle: HeaderStyle(  
                centerHeaderTitle: true,  
                formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(  
                  color: Colors.brown,  
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),  
                ),  
                formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),  
                formatButtonShowsNext: false,  
              ),  
              startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
              onDaySelected: (date, event,_) {  
                print("date");
                print(date.toUtc());  
              },
              
              builders: CalendarBuilders(  
                selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(  
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),  
                    alignment: Alignment.center,  
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(  
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,  
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),  
                    child: Text(  
                      date.day.toString(),  
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),  
                    )),  
                todayDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(  
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),  
                    alignment: Alignment.center,  
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(  
                        color: Colors.blue,  
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),  
                    child: Text(  
                      date.day.toString(),  
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),  
                    )),  
              ),  
              calendarController: _controller,  
            ));  
            
  }
```

Comment: please add those widgets and packages' name ,

Comment: i used flutter table_calendar widget, also edit my code with that library

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected date;
var initialDate = DateTime.now();

Future<void>datePicker(BuildContext context)async{
final now = DateTime.now();
final _pickDate = await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: initialDate,
  firstDate: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day),
  lastDate: DateTime(2050),
);
if (_pickDate == null) {
  return;
}
initialDate = _pickDate;
setState(() {
  selectedDate = _pickDate;
});
 }
```